# i am getting error while connecting env to mongoose

Tags: node.js, express

this is in my .env file

```
 DB_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/ecomm
```

and connection.js file is..

```
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
const {DB_URL}=process.env
console.log(process.env)
async function createConnection(){
    console.log("create connection")
    const connection=await mongoose.connect(DB_URL,{
        useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology:true,useCreateIndex: true
        })
        if (connection){
            console.log("connected")
        }

}
```

but i am getting error is....

```
(node:2304) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
```

why i am getting error?
const {DB_URL}=process.env
console.log({DB_URL}) is undefine showm in console

Comment: Do you use `dotenv` package somewhere in your code ? You need it to get your env variables from .env file copied in your node process. https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Answer (score 1):

use **dotenv** package
in connection file

````
require('dotenv').config();
connectDB();
function connectDB(){
  // mongoose.set('useCreateIndex', true)
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI // your uriName,
    {
     useNewUrlParser: true,
      poolSize: 20,
      keepAlive: 300000,
      reconnectTries:1000,
      reconnectInterval: 90000
    },function(err, db){
      if(err){
        console.log("Error in Connectiion to DB : ",err);
        setTimeout(()=>{
          connectDB();
        },5000)
      }else{
        return(db);
      }
    }); // database conneciton to azure pro database
  mongoose
  .connection
  .once('connected', () => console.log('Connected to database'));
}```
then use this code to connect it will also auto retry if connection fails
````

Answer (score 1):

On this line,

```
const {DB_URL}=process.env
```

You are using the process.env object instead of the right variable string. mongoose.connect take string URL. Please correct it.